# "Disk Locked" macOS reinstall!

Tags: macos

I have just wiped my iMac, and something must have gone wrong in the process as i cant change the boot drive by holding down option key and when i go to install reinstall macOS through macOS utilities when i select the 500GB hard drive the main one it just says "Disk is locked". Can anyone help me with this issue?

Comment: In my case the problem was that i removed Paragon NTFS files and not uninstalled it properly. So installing and uninstalling it fixed the issue – Morteza Rastgoo

Answer (score 3):

I believe you followed the official guides and you tried to factory reset your Mac and you find yourself in this situation: the disk is locked and you cannot select it for re-installation

[image]

You already tried to partition the disk multiple times but it keeps erroring with the **Error: -61**

[image]

In this case you can try:

- **Cmd+R :** For the normal reinstall but the problem still persists
- **Shift+Alt+Cmd+R :** For the internet reinstall but the problem still persists

The solution for me was to **restart** the Mac just pushing **Alt**

In this case you will see this:

[image]

Arriving at this point you need to select **not** your MacintoshHD but **the one on the right** instead which is the image of your Mac.

Once selected you will have the chance to format MacintoshHD (this time the right way) and then, **without rebooting**, choosing to reinstall MacOS:

[image]

At this point you are good to go and you will see the actual MacintoshHD which you can select to reinstall:

[image]

Special thanks to my uncle Artiade and his bloody book from the early 2000:

[image]

Comment: In my case the problem was that i removed Paragon NTFS files and not uninstalled it properly. So installing and uninstalling it fixed the issue