# Install Mac OS on external drive: disk locked

Tags: macos, install

I am trying to install Mac OS Big Sur on an external drive (Samsung portable SSD T5 256GB) following the [macworld directions](https://www.macworld.com/article/3566910/how-to-create-a-bootable-macos-big-sur-installer-drive.html). I get to the very last step, however there is a message that the disk is locked and it can't be selected, so can't install macOS on it.

[image: macOS install disk locked]

I have previously installed macOS on the drive using restore from backup, but I just want a minimal OS install, not all my stuff from a backup.

I have also tried to select the drive as the boot disk, but get a message that I can't select the drive because "the bless tool was unable to set the current boot disk".

[image: Bless tool unable to set the current boot disk]

There is a previous question [Disk Locked” macOS reinstall!](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/314099/disk-locked-macos-reinstall) however I don't think that helps, there's also a post on an [Apple discussion forum about the bless tool](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4394182), but that doesn't help either.

Any ideas on how to rectify this?

Answer (score 3):

Of course after hours of trying, I found an answer soon after I posted.

1. I connected the external drive
2. From the app store, I found Big Sur and clicked "Get". Because I'd already downloaded the installer, it started after a few moments
3. I clicked continue and accepted the Ts & Cs
4. When the "select disk to install" came up, only the internal disk was shown so I clicked the "Show all disks" button
5. The external disk was also shown, so I selected it
6. A message said the disk couldn't be used as it wasn't APFS with GUID partition map
7. I backed out of the installer, ran disk utility, erased the disk and formatted it as APFS with GUID
8. Ran steps 1 to 4 again, this time the install proceeded
9. 20 minutes later I had a bootable external drive.

The above is far simpler than the MacWorld instructions.